# How to use attributes from a retrieved row from an Azure table in a conditional?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have an azure table that I am populating/updating, and I want to only create a row if it doesn't already exist, or update the row if it is missing an attribute. I have my row check function below, but I don't know how to check that the attributes of that row are not null.

Latitude and Longitude are row attributes, as are city and state.

```
        public static async Task<bool> rowExists(CloudTable table, string city, string state)
    {
        TableOperation tOP = TableOperation.Retrieve(state, city);
        var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(tOP).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.Result == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
/*          else if(row latitude or longitude == null)
        {
            return false;
        } 
*/
        else
            return true;
    }
```

**Edit:**

Just to make the question more clear, my end-goal here is to insert a row if it does not exist. This part works fine. If the row exists, but the latitude or longitude is missing (say because of a reached query limit for the API) I want to update the row to get the missing attribute.

Comment: One follow up question: So if you query the table and find that latitude and longitude exist in the entity, then you don't want to do anything. Is this correct? Or will you be ok to update that record even if these two attributes are present?

Comment: You are correct. If both of those attributes are there, then that's all I need and I'll just move on to the next entity in my list. I'm just trying to cut down on API calls so I don't go over my query limit.

Comment: Assuming by API calls you mean calls to table storage, then even for checking you're making a call to table storage. Instead of checking first and then inserting or updating, you could simply use `Upsert` methods available in Table storage. These methods will insert the row if it does not exist otherwise it will update it. Will that solution work for you?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I should have clarified that too... I'm using a Google Maps API to get the latitude and longitude

Comment: So all you want to do is check if the entity contains the attributes (like latitude/longitude) or not. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I apologize if my question is not worded clearly.

Comment: No need to apologize....I'm a bit dense at the moment :). Posting an answer for you...see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially one way to solve this problem is to convert your result to `DynamicTableEntity` object and check if a particular property exists there. For example, you could use code like the following:

```
    public static async Task<bool> RowExists(CloudTable table, string city, string state)
    {
        TableOperation tOP = TableOperation.Retrieve(state, city);
        var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(tOP).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var entity = result.Result as DynamicTableEntity;
        if (entity == null) return false;//Entity does not exists.
        if (!entity.Properties.ContainsKey("Latitude") || !entity.Properties.ContainsKey("Longitude")) return false;//Either of these attributes do not exist in the entity.
        return true;//All's well. Let's move on to the next record :)
    }
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thank you!